# Background process suspended (tty output)

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, background-process, tty

I've a python script which calls a bash script to connect a vpn account. If I run python script from console, I can do 2FA and connect to my VPN account seamlessly. However, if I run this python script as a background process (with `nohup`, etc.) then the python process becomes suspended (`+ suspended (tty output)`) whenever I try to connect VPN and python program is not responding (looks like it is stuck in a state that expects an input).

`vpn_manager.py`:

```
connection_command = 'sh {}'.format(os.path.join(base_path, 'scripts', 'vpn.sh'))

response = subprocess.run(connection_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = response.stdout.decode('utf-8')

if 'state: Connected' in stdout:
    update_icon(environment)
```

Shell script `vpn.sh`:

```
printf "1\nUSERNAME\nPASSWORD\n2\n" | /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect VPN_HOST
```

Normally, this VPN command asks for a user name and password, then waits for me to verify it from my 2FA app on my phone.

How can I make this python code working as a background process and not interrupted with that VPN prompts?

Comment: Note that this code shouldn't be using `shell=True`; you don't need an outer shell to run an executable script. (If you _do_ need a shell, that means `vpn.sh` isn't executable or doesn't have a valid shebang; those are both bugs and should be fixed on that end).

Comment: And `subprocess.Popen(['sh', os.path.join(base_path, 'scripts', 'vpn.sh')]` will work even if you _don't_ fix those problems (but you really should: Fixing the problems will let the script select its own interpreter, so you can rewrite it sater to be a bash script instead of a sh script, or a ksh script, or another Python script, etc; and the calling code wouldn't need to know or care about the change).

Comment: ...that ideal approach would be `subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(base_path, 'scripts', 'vpn.sh')])` -- no `sh`, no `shell=True`, so you're letting `vpn.sh` tell the OS how it wants to be invoked via its `#!/bin/sh` line (or whatever else that line contains).

Comment: Note that if you don't want your subprocess interacting with the TTY, you should probably set `stdin=PIPE` or `stdin=DEVNULL` _in addition to_ any redirection of stdout (`stdout=PIPE`, if you want to read the stdout from Python).

Comment: Really, I don't see any reason for your `vpn.sh` at all here. Why not `subprocess.Popen(['/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn', '-s', 'connect', 'VPN_HOST'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate('1\nUSERNAME\nPASSWORD\n2\n')` from Python directly?

Comment: (that said, _very_ much not speaking for my employer right now, but I personally tend to recommend using [OpenConnect](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) instead of the official AnyConnect client regardless).

Comment: ...mind, `foo in response.stdout` isn't going to work the way you want it to by nature, since `response.stdout` is a file handle on a FIFO, not a string -- you'll either need to implement proper polling yourself, or use something like `pexpect` (which I strongly recommend)... unless anyconnect self-daemonizes after authentication; been long enough since I used the official client that I don't remember.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for your answers. I tried many of your suggestions. Best working version is `process = subprocess.Popen(connection_command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` with `connection_command_qa = os.path.join(base_path, 'scripts', 'vpn_qa.sh')`. When running this in PyCharm I didn't see any console output. But when I run this program from terminal, I still see `Password:` and `Answer:` outputs. Therefore it is still suspended when I try to run it as a background process.

Comment: I tested OpenConnect from terminal and it works fine. I'm going to adapt my code to use it too.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy unfortunately, it doesn't work with `subprocess.Popen(['/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn', '-s', 'connect', 'VPN_HOST'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate('1\nUSERNAME\nPASSWORD\n2\n')`. No interaction, no response, nothing.

Comment: Note that "no nothing" is _kind of_ expected. `communicate()` doesn't return until a program has closed its stdout and stderr handles, so it'll sit there and hang with no visible output until/unless anyconnect exits. That doesn't mean it isn't actually running anyconnect, though. To be able to poll a subprocess's output until a certain event occurs is doable, but the technique is much too involved to describe in a comment; there are big SO questions that do nothing but describe it.

Comment: wrt. `Password:` and `Answer:` still going to the TTY, you can fix this with the program `unbuffer`, which is part of `expect` -- it'll make a fake TTY. Make it `subprocess.Popen(['unbuffer', '/opt/cisco/anyconnect/vpn', ...`, after installing `expect` so you actually _have_ an `unbuffer` command of course.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy using `pexpect` instead of `popen` solved all of my problems. For this type of requirement `pexpect` is a way better approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pexpect` is a better approach to communicate as @CharlesDuffy suggested.

Solution with `pexpect` will be similar to below example.

```
import pexpect

failed = False
vpn = pexpect.spawn('/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect {}'.format(host))
ret = vpn.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, CONNECT_SUCCESS, CONNECT_ERR_1, CONNECT_ERR_2, ...])
if ret != 1:
    failed = True

if not failed:
    vpn.sendline('1')
    ret = vpn.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, SELECT_GROUP_SUCCESS, SELECT_GROUP_ERR_1, SELECT_GROUP_ERR_2, ...])
    if ret != 1:
        failed = True

if not failed:
    vpn.sendline(USER_NAME)
    ret = vpn.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, USER_NAME_SUCCESS, USER_NAME_ERR_1, USER_NAME_ERR_2, ...])
    if ret != 1:
        failed = True

if not failed:
    vpn.sendline(PASSWORD)
    ret = vpn.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, PASSWORD_SUCCESS, PASSWORD_ERR_1, PASSWORD_ERR_2, ...])
    if ret != 1:
        failed = True

if not failed:
    vpn.sendline(AUTHENTICATION_METHOD)
    ret = vpn.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, AUTHENTICATION_ERR_1, AUTHENTICATION_ERR_2, ...])
    if ret != 1:
        failed = True

if not failed:
    print('Connected!')
else:
    print('Failed to connect!')
```

Answer (score -1):

Send the output to a file (or named pipe)

```
printf "1\nUSERNAME\nPASSWORD\n2\n" | /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect VPN_HOST > /tmp/vpn.out
```

Then in you python script you can check that file content until you read the expected content.

Comment: Why do it that way instead of using `stdout=PIPE` in the Python code, and `read()`ing from `connection_command.stdout`, or using the Python `Popen.communicate()` call? This seems a lot more error prone (can only have one copy running at a time since the filename is constant, attackers can create their own `/tmp/vpn.out` symlink pointing to a place they control, etc) with no obvious benefit and an increase in the required code complexity.

Comment: well, the password is written to a file, so attacker may have it easier...

Comment: Not sure I follow. You're putting the password in a file either way -- `vpn.sh` one way, the Python script the other. If one's going to do something like decrypt it with a Yubikey, that can be done with either Python or shell.